# Why am I unable to watch a service's property from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

LIVE CODE: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/142/)

I have injected a service called `FileTraversal` added to a module `divkick.services`.  I Also have a module `divkick.container` with a controller named `ContainerCtrl`.

I've added a watcher function in `ContainerCtrl` and was hopeful it could watch `FileTraversal.stuff` array.

**Question:** I feel this is dumb syntax problem, **How do I watch FileTraversal.stuff from `ContrainerCtrl`**

Main App:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('divkick', [
    'divkick.services',
    'divkick.components',
    'divkick.container'
  ]);
})();
```

Controller:

```
(function () {
  angular
      .module('divkick.container', [])
      .controller('ContainerCtrl', ContainerCtrl)

  ContainerCtrl.$inject = ['FileTraversal', '$scope', '$timeout'];
  /* @ngInject */
  function ContainerCtrl(FileTraversal, $scope, $timeout) {
    /* jshint validthis: true */
    var main = this;

    activate();

    ////////////////

    function activate() {
      $scope.$watch(
          // This function returns the value being watched. It is called for each turn of the $digest loop
          function() { return FileTraversal.stuff; },
          // This is the change listener, called when the value returned from the above function changes (but not working) :(
          function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {

              console.log(newValue);
            } else {
              console.log('nope');
            }
          }
      );
    }
  }
})();
```

Service:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  var fs = require('fs');
  var glob = require("glob");
  angular
      .module('divkick.services', [])
      .factory('FileTraversal', FileTraversal);


  /* @ngInject */
  function FileTraversal() {
    var service = {
      stuff: [],
      check: check
    };

    return service;

    ////////////////

    function check(filePath) {
      glob(filePath + '/**/*{.png,.jpg,.gif}', function (er, files) {
        if(er) return er;
        service.stuff = files;
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

I tried watchcollection like this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(

          function() { return FileTraversal.stuff; },
          function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
              // Only increment the counter if the value changed
              console.log(newValue);
            } else {
              console.log('nope');
            }
          }
      );
```

Comment: did you try `$watchCollection` ?

Comment: I just did :( no luck

Comment: try this trick `$scope.list=FileTraversal.stuff ; `  now add watch in list

Comment: I added $scope.list=FileTraversal.stuff; and used it in the watcher.  No luck?

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: Let me try... bit complicated too remake let me see tho.  5 mins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91341/discussion-between-matthew-harwood-and-anik-islam-abhi).

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Live code at top of my question. If I'm not around I really appericate the help.  I check asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try watch collection instead of watch

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function () {
    return FileTraversal.stuff;
}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("check")
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {

        console.log(newValue);
    } else {
        console.log('nope');
    }
});
```

**N:B:**

you didn't add ng-controller in view in your fiddle . may be that's a typo

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/144/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `$watch` instead of `$watchCollection`.

`$watch` is currently looking at a property that points to an array. Even if the array changes, the property that points to the array doesn't change - the pointer is the same. So `$watch` doesn't detect this.

If you use `$watchCollection`, angular will know to examine the collection to see if any of the elements in the collection have changed.

See [The Three Watch Depths of AngularJS](http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html) for more info.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XzzMf8o5hophuoOvEvfV?p=preview)

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
  .factory('Factory', Factory)
;

function MainController(Factory, $scope) {
  var main = this;
  main.factory = Factory;
  main.addToArray = function() {
    main.factory.array.push('added');
  };
  
  // watching primitive
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return Factory.primitive;
  }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal === oldVal) {
      console.log('primitive unchanged');
    }
    else {
      console.log('primitive changed');
    }
  });
  
  // watching array
  $scope.$watchCollection(function() {
    return Factory.array;
  }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal === oldVal) {
      console.log('array unchanged');
    }
    else {
      console.log('array changed');
    }
  });
}

function Factory() {
  return {
    primitive: 'foo',
    array: []
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainController as main">
      <input ng-model="main.factory.primitive" />
      <button ng-click='main.addToArray()'>Add to array</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```